# ionic 4 increase checkbox icon size

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to increase the icon size in `ion-checkbox` but I couldn't find a way to do.

I tried `font-size`, `--size` properties but they are increasing the overall width and height of the background instead of the check icon.

[image]

HTML

```
<ion-checkbox
        color="secondary"
        slot="start"
        size="large">
</ion-checkbox>
```

CSS

```
ion-checkbox {
    --background: var(--background-color);
    --background-checked: var(--background-color);
    --checkmark-color: var(--color-blue-medium);
    --border-color: transparent;
    --border-color-checked: transparent;
   /* increasing overall width not the check icon size */
    --size:48px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Size of the icon can be modified by the zoom property in style.

In .scss file

```
   .my-icon { zoom : 2.0;}
```

In .html file

```
<ion-icon class="my-icon"></ion-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style the icon size, since it's a Shadow DOM.

Shadow DOM can be styled only if CSS4 variables are in use (which is not the case here).

(see [article](https://www.joshmorony.com/shadow-dom-usage-in-ionic-web-components))